# How to receiver audio file twilio whatsapp callback

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

In `Twilio console WhatsApp` setting I've config the `A MESSAGE COMES IN` callback for receiver message from WhatsApp user. If the user sends an image, the call back has a parameter is `MediaUrl0` to get the image. But if a user sends an audio file, no param in the callback to get it.

Any way to get the audio file? Please help me. thank you.

Comment: I suggest you to write a ticket to Twilio support. I've had experience with them and I have to say they have one of the best support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

At this time, Twilio [does not support incoming media in WhatsApp messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#receiving-a-whatsapp-message). This support is being worked on.