# Twilio WhatsApp Sandbox How to get media URL MediaUrl0 (audio files)

Tags: sandbox, whatsapp, twilio-api, facebook-webhooks

I am using the Twilio Sandbox for WhatsApp and when I send an image the payload I receive in my webhook works fine, I can get the url of the image but doesn't work with audio files (voice messages).

I'm facing an issue with the audios, if I send a voice message from WhatsApp, the payload in my webhook does not include the audio url.

Here the payload:

```
{
  "SmsMessageSid": "SMf79a4b49251969d1c0cf25d7dXXXXXXX",
  "NumMedia": "0",
  "SmsSid": "SMf79a4b49251969d1c0cf25d7dXXXXXXX3",
  "SmsStatus": "received",
  "Body": "",
  "To": "whatsapp:+1415XXXXXXX",
  "NumSegments": "1",
  "MessageSid": "SMf79a4b49251969d1c0cf25d7dab11313",
  "AccountSid": "AC33e5010eecfa033d3c03aaa4faef5561",
  "From": "whatsapp:+52155XXXXXXXX",
  "ApiVersion": "2010-04-01"
}
```

I expected the url media like this:

```
 "MediaUrl0": "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC33e5010eecfa033d3c03aaa4faef5561/Messages/MM637c2240c42ae13b481451cdbde7072e/Media/ME2789cc6ce84b1d73d66eb9135bd3253a"
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050997/receive-whatsapp-voice-message-in-twilio), Whatsapp recordings have an issue and are not supported yet.

In another [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54067735/10209296), a Twilio dev evangelist says they're working on a solution.